# sorl-thumbnail URLField instead of ImageField

Tags: python, django, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I have a bunch of images uploaded to Amazon S3 and I want to use sorl on them in the way, so sorl wouldn't relocate files into upload_to directory. Like if I've used URLField instead of FileField (which is require actual file content). Is it possible?

**UPDATE**:
Here is an example:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Thumbnail(Model):
    image = ImageField(upload_to='.', storage=S3BotoStorage)

thumb = Thumbnail(image=File(S3BotoStorage.open('/path/to/image'))
thumb.save()
```

This code will download image to server and then upload it to the same S3 storage, which, well, takes time. It's completely unnecessary if thumbnails are already created, so my idea was to use some kind of `URLField`, which I would point to my S3 storage in order to avoid this problem.